# Table of loaded minibuffer completions

Tags: completion

I would like to make a table that shows what minibuffer completion frameworks have been loaded from `icomplete`, `icomplete-vertical`, `ivy`, `vertico` and `helm`.  As well as the minibuffer completion  framework currently in place.

Have started with the following

```
(defun make-table ()
  (interactive)
  (table-insert 4 5)
  (table-forward-cell)
  (table-insert-sequence "icomplt-horz" 1 4 1 'center)
  (table-forward-cell 4)
  (table-insert-sequence "icomplt-vert" 1 4 1 'center)
  (table-release))
```

Have not figured out how to move by row yet.  Most of the examples I have seen were about org-tables.

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit the question and add your attempts.

Comment: You can create an Org table in an Org mode file and then use `org-table-convert` to convert it to a `table.el` table.

Comment: I would like to insert the table in a dedicated buffer actually, which would not necessarily be in org-mode.

Comment: OK - but just FYI, you *could* generate the table in a temp Org mode buffer and then cut and paste it into your dedicated buffer; or switch major modes on the dedicated buffer, first to Org mode, generate the table and then switch back to the original mode. All roads lead to Rome... In any case, the most important thing is to calculate the contents of the table. Formatting the table is a minor concern (although depending on what you want to format it to, a complicated and fiddly "minor" concern).

Comment: What are the main problems with the normal non-org table?

Comment: I don't know if there are any: I just don't use them.

Comment: Section 25.15 of the emacs manual should be helpful here.

Comment: The problem is that making a table with elisp commands is a struggle as there is not much information.

Comment: Try reading the Commentary in the `table.el` file: it may have some information about programmatic interfaces. That's the second place I look for information about a package. This one has an extensive Commentary.

Comment: Am trying to find how I can insert text in a cell.  There should be some details how to make tables in the Elisp Reference Manual.

Comment: That's an entirely unreasonable expectation. The Elisp Reference manual documents Emacs Lisp, the basic functions that Emacs provides out of the box and some topics of interest to programmers (e.g. debugging and profiling) - *that's it*!  In particular, it does not cover the (thousands of) additional packages (even if some of them are now built-in to Emacs: e.g. Gnus, Org mode, Calc and many more are described in their own manuals. Most of those do not provide programming information: you need to read the sources for that.

Comment: Have you considered using [table-capture](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Table-Conversion.html)? Seems the easiest path to me...

Comment: I want to be able to colour the background of a cell.

Comment: These are additional requirements that have nothing to do with the question. Ask a different question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the most important thing here is to get the data: formatting the data as a textual table is of secondary importance, but you seem stuck on that, so here's one way to proceed.

You write a function that produces the data as text with column fields delimited by some character and rows delimited by (e.g.) newlines. Then you use `M-x table-capture` to convert the region to a table.

For example if you have text like this:

```
Framework@Present?
built-in@yes
icomplete@no
ivy@yes
helm@no
```

then marking the region appropriately, doing `M-x table-capture`, and answering the questions ("Column delimiter regexp: @", "Row delimiter regexp: C-q C-j", "Justify (default left): RET", "Minimum cell width (default 5): RET") will create the table:

```
+----------+--------+
|Frameworks|Present?|
+----------+--------+
|built-in  |yes     |
+----------+--------+
|helm      |no      |
+----------+--------+
|ivy       |no      |
+----------+--------+
|icomplete |no      |
+----------+--------+
|vertico   |no      |
+----------+--------+
```

(I get white letters on a blue background in each cell - YMMV).

You can do that programatically, assuming you know the bounds of the region, with:

```el
(table-capture beg end "@" "\n")
```

where `beg` and `end` are the beginning and the end of the region that you are interested in. For experimentation, you can type that expression in your text buffer and execute it with `C-x C-e` after the closing paren. If you don't like the result, undo with `C-x u` and re-execute the command after whatever changes you deem necessary.

The main problem is to produce the text that will become the table, but now you don't have to worry about the table at all.  You can produce the table in a form that's convenient for manipulation, then convert that representation into text that can be inserted in the buffer and then insert that text and call `table-capture` as described above to convert it into a table.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```el
  (defun make-table ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((beg (point)))
      (insert (text-of-table (table-of-frameworks)))
      (table-capture beg (point) "@" "\n")))
```

where I postulate the existence of two additional functions: `table-of-frameworks`
and `text-of-table`.

The function `table-of-frameworks`
produces a list of completion frameworks and whether they are loaded in the current emacs
in the form of two-element lists like this:

```el
(("ivy" "yes") ("helm" "no") ...)
```

It does not worry about the built-in completion since that's always available:

```el
  (defun table-of-frameworks ()
    "The returned table is represented as a list of rows; each row is
  represented as a two-element list: the name of the framework and
  the string \"yes\" or \"no\", depending on whether the framework is present or not."
    (let ((frameworks '(ivy helm vertico icomplete)))
      (mapcar (lambda (x) (list (symbol-name x) (if (featurep x) "yes" "no"))) frameworks)))
```

The `text-of-table` function function converts this representation of the table into a single string that can be `insert`ed as the `make-table` function does:

```el
  (defun text-of-table (table)
    "Insert a header and the first row  and then loop over the table,
  formatting each row and concatenating the rows with newlines."
    (concat "Framework@Present?\n" "built-in@yes\n"
            (mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "%s@%s\n" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x))) table "\n")))
```

Comment: `table.el` looks as if it was designed under the assumption that the table would be edited interactively rather than from elisp.  It could have a lot of potential, if some could contribute to the code and doc if it proves necessary.

Comment: I do not want to have the row separators, between `built-in` and `vertico`.

Comment: AFAIK, you get them whether you want them or not: `table.el` is built this way. With Org mode tables, you can put hline separators where you want them (OTOH, if you want them everywhere that gets to be a pain).