# Table according to numeric selector

Tags: table

I have the following [elisp functions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74433/table-of-loaded-minibuffer-completions) to show a table by calling `make-table`.

Associated with each completion framework there is a number. 0 means feature not loaded; 1 feature loaded; 2 feature loaded and user performed customisation; 3 feature loaded, customisation performed and mode enabled.

The information is stored in a vector array `(setq selectr [3 2 1 1 0])`, corresponding to the completion features (icomplete, icomplete-vertical, ivy, vertico, helm).

The intention is to produce the following table

```
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|Completion        |1    |2    |3    |
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+    
|built-in          |xxxxx|xxxxx|xxxxx| 
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|icomplete         |xxxxx|xxxxx|xxxxx|
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|icomplete-vertical|xxxxx|xxxxx|     |
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|ivy               |xxxxx|xxxxx|     |
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|vertico           |xxxxx|     |     |
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|helm              |     |     |     |
+------------------+-----+-----+-----+


(defun text-of-table (table)
  "Insert a header and the first row  and then loop over the
table, formatting each row and concatenating the rows with
newlines."

  (concat "Completion |1    |2    |3    | \n"
      "built-in  |xxxxx|xxxxx|xxxxx| \n"
      (mapconcat
         ;; function
         (lambda (x)
           (format "%s| %s | %s \n" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x) (nth 2 x)))
             ;;
         table
         "\n")))

(defun table-of-frameworks ()
  "The returned table is represented as a list of rows; each row
is represented as a four-element list: the name of the framework
and the strings \"xxxxx\", depending on whether the number is    
0, 1, 2 ,or 3."

  (let ( (frameworks
        '(icomplete icomplete-vertical ivy vertico helm)) )

    (mapcar
       ;; Function
       (lambda (x)
     (list (symbol-name x)
           (if (featurep x) "xxxxx|xxxxx|xxxxx|" "|||")))
       ;;
       frameworks)))

(defun make-table ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg (point)))
    (insert (text-of-table (table-of-frameworks)))
    (table-capture beg (point) "|" "\n")))
```

Comment: I don't understand the specification: care to elaborate? What do the columns mean? Please edit the question: do not clarify in a comment.

Comment: Associated with each completion framework there is a number.  `0` means feature not loaded; `1` feature loaded; `2` feature loaded and user performed customisation; `3` feature loaded, customisation performed and mode enabled.

Comment: *Please edit the question: do not clarify in a comment*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq-mapn` to iterate over two sequences simultaneously.
Then you can use `mapconcat` to create the string, and use `y` (from your `selectr` sequence) as a counter in its 'function' argument. There exists the nice 'special form' `prog1` that makes it possible to lower the counter after the if form, but return the value of the if form (the first function in the `prog1` body).

After applying these 'tricks' your first two functions would look as follows, and produce the result you ask for:

```lisp
(defun text-of-table (table)
  "Insert a header and the first row  and then loop over the
table, formatting each row and concatenating the rows with
newlines."

  (concat "Completion |1    |2    |3    | \n"
          "built-in  |xxxxx|xxxxx|xxxxx| \n"
          (mapconcat
           ;; function
           (lambda (x)
             (format "%s|%s\n" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x)))
           table
           "\n")))

(defun table-of-frameworks ()
  "The returned table is represented as a list of rows; each row
is represented as a four-element list: the name of the framework
and the strings \"xxxxx\", depending on whether the number is
0, 1, 2 ,or 3."

  (let ((frameworks '(icomplete icomplete-vertical ivy vertico helm))
        (selectr [3 2 1 1 0]))

    (seq-mapn (lambda (x y)
                (list (symbol-name x)
                      (if (featurep x)
                          (mapconcat (lambda (s)
                                       (prog1
                                           (if (> y 0) (concat "xxxxx" s) s)
                                         (setq y (1- y))))
                                     (split-string "|||" "" t))
                        "|||")))
              frameworks selectr)))
```

or you could use the simple

```lisp
(mapconcat #'identity
           (append (make-list y "xxxxx|") (make-list (- 3 y) "|")))
```

and there are probably many more clever ways to achieve it.

Simply load the functions above and use your `make-table` function

As mentioned by @nickd, the code would probably be more robust when you first associate the framework with the selector (e.g. in an alist), and then simply map over the association(-list) (and appropriately use the `car` and `cdr`).

Comment: It would be better if the selector was attached to the appropriate framework to begin with. Parallel lists have to be kept in sync manually, making it twice as likely that an error will creep in.

Comment: Good point! I simply assume(d) that the `frameworks` and the `selectr` are separate for some 'good' reason.

Comment: I doubt it: that's why I asked for clarification.