# Adapting list according to array

Tags: list

I want to construct a list of lists using the function `pmchart`

```
(pmchart '("Peter" "John") [3 2] 5)
```

to produce

```
'(("Peter" "xxxxx" "xxxxx" "xxxxx" "")
  ("John"  "xxxxx" "xxxxx" ""      ""))
```

The function takes a list DESCR of N string elements; and an associated array SELECTR,
also of N elements but composed of integers.

Each list represents cells in a row of a table.
Each element of DESCR is used as the first element of each sub-list.  Whilst the corresponding DESCR value would be the number of "xxxxx" blocks
in the remaining elements of each list, with the rest being empty strings.

I would also require a numeric value that determines the total number of elements in each sub-list, call it M.

```
(defun pmchart (descr selectr m)
  "TODO."
        
  (seq-mapn
    (lambda (x y)
       (message "x: %S" x)
       (list y 
             (mapcar
                (append (make-list x "xxxxx")
                        (make-list (- m x) ""))
             x))
       selectr
       descr)))
```

Comment: Please try to learn from answers. You already asked a very similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/table-according-to-numeric-selector). And from that answer, the answer to this question is straightforward. Also, instead of responding to @NickD his request to clarify your question, you are posting an even worse explained question here. Please respond to @NickD about how to associate the selector with the framework first, or explain how the numbers are related to the rows in `complt-chart`. Although I know what you mean, you should make your question clear first.

Comment: See the comments on the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/table-according-to-numeric-selector).

Comment: I see.  Just been using the same example a lot.

Comment: This is simpler to avoid all the calls to `list` `symbol-name`, `featurep`, `mapconcat`, `lambda`.  Se we do not to check for feature.  Meaning that "vertico" is just a string, any string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table according to numeric selector](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/table-according-to-numeric-selector)

Comment: This is a much simpler version as it does not require testing for a feature, just printing a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me 'extract' the answer from the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/table-according-to-numeric-selector)

```lisp
(mapcar (lambda (n)
          (append (make-list n "xxxxx")
                  (make-list (- 3 n) "")))
        [3 2 2 1 0])
```

You should come up with how to create the 'chart' you want yourself, as you do not explain how the numbers are associated with the frameworks or 'rows in the chart'.

Comment: B.t.w. the `selectr` must be a vector per se?

Comment: I am getting `(void-function map)` with your answer.  Regarding the vector per se, would you suggest a way to do things better?

Comment: I could change the array into a list.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that map was actually a function in the 'cl-lib' library. But I see that mapcar can be used to map over all kinds of sequences (I thought it could be only used for lists), so I'll just modify the answer to use mapcar.

Comment: It is all good, except for one small thing.  The start of each row has also a string.  Perhaps store them in a list and pass that through as well?

Comment: I have already answered the (very similar) question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74449/26163). I have adapted the answer to use `seq-mapn` instead of `map` to avoid dependencies. Please look at the answer there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140405/discussion-between-dalanicolai-and-avacha).

Comment: It is not important how to generate the array numbers.  The function just takes the numbers as supplies.  In addition I want to introduce each element from a list of strings each to be inserted as the first cell in each row.

Comment: You have extracted the answer from another question, but this now question is an extension of that answer, intended to handle both an array of numbers, and a list of strings to be inserted at the beginning of each list.

Comment: I think the possibility is to apply nested `mapcar` calls.

Comment: I've extracted this answer, because you have extracted this question (it is not an extension). Anyway, review how I have used `seq-mapn` (iterate over two lists simultaneously) in the other answer. You should really be able to come up with a solution here yourself. Both answers also show you how to use append (although you could use `cons` here). Anyway, the solution is extremely simple if you understand the other answer. Just replace `mapcar` with `seq-mapn` and modify the body of the lambda accordingly (hint, add a `cons` or add an extra element to the `append` form).