# seq-mapn with array in lambda function

Tags: list

I am using the following function to make a list of lists.

```
(defun pmchart selectr nc)
  "TODO."

  
  (seq-mapn
     (lambda (p q)
       (message "p: %S" p)
       (list q (append (make-list p "xxxxx")
               (make-list (- nc 1 p) ""))))
       selectr
       descr))
```

Calling

```
(pmchart '("Peter" "Paul") [3 2] 5)
```

gives the list

```
'(("Peter" ("xxxxx" "xxxxx" "xxxxx" "")) 
  ("Paul" ("xxxxx" "xxxxx" "" "")))
```

But what I would like to get is this

```
'(("Peter" "xxxxx" "xxxxx" "xxxxx" "") 
  ("Paul" "xxxxx" "xxxxx" "" ""))
```

Comment: This is such a bad question. You’re not even saying what problem you are having, or what you have tried, or anything. You’re just dumping your code and assuming that everyone has read your last 20 bad questions.

Comment: I am finding it very hard to do.

Comment: I might give up on using `seq-mapn`.

Comment: If I had an hour to solve a problem and my life depended on the solution, I would spend the first 55 minutes determining the proper question to ask… for once I know the proper question, I could solve the problem in less than five minutes.

— Albert Einstein (source: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/power-asking-right-questions-oluwaseyi-kehinde-peters/)

Comment: In other words, spend more time on phrasing your questions and removing errors from them (What is the relation between `table-of-frameworks` and `pmcharts`? Why you pass only 1 argument to `seq-mapn`? etc...). You might already learn a lot from doing that, and you might get extra insights while trying to explain in detail what you are trying to do and which part you get stuck on.

Comment: A long question is better than a bad question. You could also break up your question(s). After breaking up the question (for yourself), you might want to review [one of the most essential sections of the elisp reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html), and try (like making a puzzle), how you would achieve to build up one of the individual inner lists of your table.

Comment: Good luck with these suggestions!

Comment: Have done some progress now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140491/discussion-between-dalanicolai-and-avacha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your request...

Instead of adding a `make-list` in the append, (where otherwise, I would have used simply `(list q)`), I would simply prepend the 'description' using cons:

```lisp
(defun pmchart (descr selectr &optional nc)
  (seq-mapn (lambda (d s)
              (cons d (append (make-list s "xxxxx")
                              (make-list (- (or nc 5) 1 s) ""))))
            descr
            selectr))

(pmchart '("Peter" "Paul") [3 2])
```

Also, as you can see, I would probably make the 'number of columns' optional with a default value (as I guess you will have some default use for this).

Comment: If you now compare this answer to the answers [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74461/26163) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74449/26163), I hope you now conclude that the solution indeed was very simple (and also that the second linked answer, is a complete answer to your original question already). Your solution, to me, suggest that you did not yet 'master' the [fundamental functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/car-cdr-_0026-cons.html).

Comment: I have been playing with cons actually.  And have noticed that I can pass a list to `cons`, and the list will be inserted at the beginning of a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I have introduced `q` by making a list with one element containing `q`.

```
(defun pmchart (descr selectr nc)
  "TODO."
  
  (seq-mapn
     (lambda (p q)
       (message "p: %S" p)
       (append (make-list 1 q)
               (make-list p "xxxxx")
               (make-list (- nc 1 p) "")))
       selectr
       descr))
```

Comment: Did you read [the section(s) I suggested](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/cons.html)?

Comment: I do not see reason why the solution would fail.

Comment: Personally, I prefer elegance and simplicity... but your solution works fine too, of course.

Comment: Would you share your solution, now that I have solved it?

Comment: Fine, it is only minimally different, as it is also based on the solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74461/26163) of course...